# Complete a HTTP post request first before executing the next HTTP post in a loop

Tags: node.js, angular

I have this loop where it every time it will loop it will make a HTTP post request.

```
for(let i = 1; i < this.data.length; i++) {
      let arr = this.data[i];
      this.http.post('link here', {
        name: arr[0],
        gender: arr[1],
        course: arr[2],
        year: arr[3]
      }).subscribe(
        (data: any) => console.log("succes at " + i),
        error => console.log(error + "at" + arr[0])
      );
    }
```

But I found out that it doesn't wait for a HTTP post to finish before it proceeds to the next loop and executes the next HTTP post. What I want to achieve is to complete first a HTTP post before proceeding to the next loop executing the HTTP post. I wont to achieve this since I want the order of data saved on my database will on the same order of the array on my loop. Any ideas how to do it? Im using anuglar and nodejs btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a recursive function, like so

```
example(i, limit, data) {
    let arr = this.data[i];
    this.http.post('link here', {
        name: arr[0],
        gender: arr[1],
        course: arr[2],
        year: arr[3]
    }).subscribe(
        (data: any) => console.log("succes at " + i),
        error => console.log(error + "at" + arr[0]),
        () => ++i < limit ? this.example(i, limit) : null
    );
}
```

And to start the loop, invoke it using:

```
this.example(0, this.data.length, this.data)
```

This way, the next iteration of `example` is not invoked until the previous subscription has complete

Comment: And strongly consider adding a timeout so you don't slam the server with 500 requests per second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aync/await` for it.

In angular `http.get/post/etc` by default returns a `Observable<T>` but has a `toPromise()` method to make it a Promise. Once you get a promise you can use `async/await`

I am adding a POC, don't know if it will work or not. I will edit it for syntax errors.

```
async function getAsyncData() {
    for (let i = 1; i < this.data.length; i++) {
        let arr = this.data[i];
        const data = await this.http.post('link here', {
            name: arr[0],
            gender: arr[1],
            course: arr[2],
            year: arr[3]
        })
        .toPromise();

        console.log(data);
    }
}
```